# How to create a mock object with jest and typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am writing a jest test where I want to mock a service to return an object of the correct type according to its interface. The type of object to be returned has a complicated constructor that would require a lot of work to create and keep typescript happy.  What is the best/easiest way to achieve this (code sample below)

```
import Auth, { CognitoUser } from '@aws-amplify/auth';

jest.mock('@aws-amplify/auth');
const mockedAuth = Auth as jest.Mocked<typeof Auth>;

const loggedInUser = new CognitoUser(); \\ Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
mockedAuth.signIn.mockResolvedValue(loggedInUser);
```

In the above code the test will run and create an instance of CognitoUser with all the functions stubbed out, but TypeScript complains that I am not passing the required parameters. Is there a way I can make it happy without adding @ts-ignore?

Note: the parameter the constructor is expecting is of type ICognitoUserData, which itself has required fields that would go many levels deep.

Comment: A mocked object still requires the arguments it would usually have. Is passing a mocked `ICognitoUserData` not an option?

Comment: How do I create a mock of ICognitoUserData? Ideally I don't want to traverse down the tree providing mocks for every field on every parameter, i.e. ICognitoUserData has a required field of type CognitoUserPool, which has a required field of type ICognitoUserPoolData etc. I really just want a mock CognitoUser so that I can stub the getUsername function on it etc.

Comment: I could do: ```const loggedInUser = new CognitoUser({} as ICognitoUserData);```. It feels like a bit of a workaround, so I would still be interested to know if there is a better way.

Comment: If that works then why not, if you're not testing anything on that object why would you want anything more than that? *unless the mocked `getUsername` return value is modified by that data in which case you'll want to add the relevant data that lets you test that method. Then again a pure mock should not care about implementation.

Comment: I'm new to TypeScript so just trying to understand best practice. To me this felt like I am bypassing typescript by just telling it that this empty object is of a specific type when it clearly isn't. Coming from a Java background I was expecting to do something like Mockito.mock(CognitoUser.class) to get an actual mocked implementation. But I guess it's a different mindset.

Comment: Yes, a very different mindset indeed. Best practices would say to never do this in production code `{} as Something`, but in tests specifically, it can be a very useful tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across this question and wants the answer, the best I could get was:

`const loggedInUser = new CognitoUser({} as ICognitoUserData);`

Seems perfectly acceptable to just cast objects to the desired types within tests.